# how to access data form Instance of ModelName / ProviderName in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, model, widget, provider

I have a Challenge Provider which gets data from a API. I store the data in a `List<Challenge>` array. in challenge screen, I get the `List<Challenge>` array. now what I get is `Instance of 'ChallengeModel'`.

In `ListView.builder()`, if I do `challenge[index].title` I get null.

code is as bellow :

ChallengeModel:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChallengeModel {

  int id;
  int status;
  String title;
  String description;
  String startDate;
  String endDate;

  ChallengeModel({
    @required id,
    @required title,
    @required description,
    @required startDate,
    @required endDate,
    @required status,
  });



}
```

In Provider how I add the `ChallengeModel` Data in the array:

```dart
_challenges.add(
         ChallengeModel(
           id: result['id'],
           title: result['title'],
           description: result['description'],
           startDate: result['start_date'],
           endDate: result['end_date'],
           status: finalStatus,
         )
        );
```

Challenges Screen:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final challengeProvider = Provider.of<ChallengesProvider>(context);
    var challenges = challengeProvider.items;
    print(challenges);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: challenges.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "${challenges[index].title}",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Terminal Print Result for the API data and above provider items.

```dart
flutter: {
   id:3,
   group_id:1,
   title:Demo Challlenge,
   description:<p>lorem epson</p>,
   start_date:2019-12-12 00:00:00,
   end_date:2020-01-13 00:00:00,
   status_id:2,
   creator_id:1,
   moderator_id:1,
   created_at:2019-12-12 14:26:57,
   updated_at:2019-12-12 14:26:57,
   deleted_at:null,
   teams:[
      {
         id:1,
         group_id:1,
         name:Havens Blade,
         logo:https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200,
         status_id:2,
         creator_id:2,
         moderator_id:2,
         created_at:2019-12-11 01:27:16,
         updated_at:2019-12-11 01:27:16,
         deleted_at:null,
         pivot:{
            challenge_id:3,
            team_id:1
         }
      },
      {
         id:2,
         group_id:1,
         name:Let's Do it, 
         logo: https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200, 
         status_id: 2, 
        creator_id: 1, 
        moderator_id: 1, 
        created_at: 2019-12-11 14:34:36, 
        updated_at: 2019-12-11 14:34:36, 
        deleted_at: null, 
        {
        id: 3, 
        group_id: 1, 
        name: OneMORE, 
        logo: https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200, 
        status_id: 2, 
        creator_id: 1, 
        moderator_id: 1, 
        created_at: 2019-12-11 14:35:30, 
        updated_at: 2019-12-11 14:35<…>

flutter: --------------------------------------
flutter: challenges final completed
flutter: [Instance of 'ChallengeModel', Instance of 'ChallengeModel', Instance of 'ChallengeModel']
```

Comment: got the answer from reference. it was the `this` key word in the model which was missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @override
  String toString() => 'AllDataModel(data: $data)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant AllDataModel other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other.data == data;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => data.hashCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword was missing in the model, like below.

```dart
class ChallengeModel {

  int id;
  int status;
  String title;
  String description;
  String startDate;
  String endDate;

  ChallengeModel({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.startDate,
    @required this.endDate,
    @required this.status,
  });



}
```

due to this `.title` or any other data was not accessible.